# Connecting via SSH to Amazon EKS EC2 Instance to perform admin tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-eks

I am trying to remote into my Amazon EKS EC2 Instance to apply the AWS authenticator configuration map YAML file but cannot figure it out.

I have the EKS Cluster, Stack and EC2 instance already running at this point. I have been walking myself through the user guide for setting EKS up and now at the point to where I need to be able to remote into the server to apply the YAML file for amazon's authentication map. I am unsure as how to complete this last step.

I did find a post where someone created an EC2 instance ON the same VPC but I feel like that is a workaround to actually doing it correctly and exposing your worker nodes via the EC2 instance that does not belong on that VPC.

Could anyone please help me round out these last steps? Thank you in advance as this is all a learning process to me!

Comment: You do not need to log into an instance to do this. Just get the kubeconfig from AWS for your cluster and then use kubectl from your own desktop. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html. Unless the EKS control plane is created using private access control. Then you will need to log into an instance.